# Right continuity of infimum on rational numbers

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, supremum-and-infimum, weak-convergence

[image: Theorem with a piece of proof]

I am trying to understand a piece of this proof (of a version of Helly's theorem). I understood everything except the passage in which the author says that $F(x)$ is right continuous. How can I prove that? Is it so clear from the contruction he made?
Also, is it true that $F$ is continuous on rationals? And why?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we know that $F$ is increasing, to prove that $F$ is right continuous, it is sufficient to show that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $ y > x $ such that $F(y) < F(x) + \epsilon$. So take $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon >0$. Then by definition we can find $y \in \mathbb{Q}$ for which $x < y$ and $F(y) < F(x) + \epsilon$. Therefore $F$ is right continuous. For the second question $F$ is not necesarrily continuous at rationals. For instance let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ supported on $\{0\}$, and $\mu_n = \mu$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. In this case $F = 0$ on $(-\infty, 0)$ and $F=1$ on $[0, \infty)$. Thus $F$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: Thank you, I had just arrived to first answer. It was simple. For the second question I needed that $F$ was continuous on a dense subset of $\mathbf{R}$ so I thought to rationals. Instead I have simply that the set of continuity of $F$ is dense itself cause its complement is countable. However thank you, i could not figure out that counterexample.

Comment: Could I ask only why (without the condition of tightness) we cannot say that limits to $\pm\infty$ are $1$ and $0$? It's because sequence doesn't converge uniformly?